# Using an external tool to store items/weapons

Tags: borderlands-2

A long time ago diablo 2 had an external tool called [ATMA](http://atma.incgamers.com/), which you could use to store items outside of the game. Which removed the need for mule characters. I was wondering if borderlands 2 has a similar tool.

So a program that you use to store your weapons/items outside of the game. Not using the ingame bank.

That way you can keep all those rare weapons you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.gib.me/category/games/borderlands-2/
[Use at your own risk](http://blog.gib.me/2014/07/15/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-237/comment-page-1/#comment-23828). Rick makes great stuff and addresses the malware detection openly, so I trust it.

How to:

1. Hit the Download link.
2. Extract anywhere you want.
3. Run Gibbed.Borderlands2.SaveEdit.exe.
4. Open (shortcut Ctrl+O).
5. Navigate to C:\Users[your user account]\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\7656119[your Steam ID].
6. Open the .sav that is the character that has the item you wish to store.
7. Select Backpack tab.
8. Select item to store.
9. Copy Code (shortcut Ctrl+C or right-click and select option).
10. Store code in your desired textual format.

To give it to a character, put the code in your clipboard (copy it) (it's OK if there are spaces and/or [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)s before and/or after it), then select the Paste Code option (in the Backpack tab).

Comment: It worked for me. While not as grand as the atma tool (which had the ingame stats of the item clearly visible). It was what I was looking for. Thanks.